# Getting error while installing Eclipse on mac

Tags: eclipse

Can somebody please help to resolve the eclipse installation (Eclipse IDE 2018-12) issue on mac book.

I removed existing eclipse before installing new version.

Below is the error that I am getting:

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2018-12 in 0.275s
    [2019-01-04 22:44:23] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
    [2019-01-04 22:44:23] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:733)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3334)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3262)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3243)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3143)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1111)
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=_Users_QATest_eclipse_jee-2018-122_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
      java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: /Users/QATest/.p2/pool/plugins/org.apache.xalan_2.7.1.v201005080400.jar
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:733)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3334)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3262)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3243)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3143)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1111)
      Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
```

Comment: what is your installed java version?

Comment: Have you checked this site? https://beginnersbook.com/2016/04/how-to-install-eclipse-on-mac-os-x/